# How to decode inconsistent JSON data with Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct, decoding

First question:
I am using this API of type JSON, but there is some inconsistent data, in the example below there is an array of measures, which sometimes consist only out of "uri" & "label", but sometimes it has a nested array of "qualified ". I am trying to decode this in Swift version 9.2, using structs. How do I deal with inconsistent array's?

Second question: "measures" in some parts is called "measure". How do I deal with inconsistent labels?

```
"measures" : [ {
    "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_serving",
    "label" : "Serving"
}, {
    "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_stalk",
    "label" : "Stalk",
    "qualified" : [ [ {
        "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Qualifier_medium",
        "label" : "medium"
    }]]

}]
```

```
struct Hints: Codable {
    let food: Food
    let measures: [Measure]
}
struct Measure: Codable {
    let uri: String
    let label : String
    let qualified : [[Qualified]]
}
struct Qualified: Codable {
    let uri: String
    let label : String
}


I really appreciate your help.
```

Comment: Implement your own `init(from decoder: Decoder)`. Read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: You could use ObjectMapper pod, where extend the class from Mappable and create the mapping. Object mapper will automatically handle mapping from/to JSON and if there is any missing keys in the JSON file it will set its value to nil. I. An post a piece of code explaining how to use it if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Your decoding will work if you make the `qualified` property optional

```
struct Measure: Codable {
    let uri: String
    let label : String
    let qualified : [[Qualified]]?
}
```

Since Qualified contains the two first properties as Measure and we made the last one optional you could even do without Qualified and define Measure like this

```
struct Measure: Codable {
    let uri: String
    let label : String
    let qualified : [[Measure]]?
}
```